# prevent print time out exception message

Tags: java, connection-timeout

l use try catch to catch connect time out exception the program work correctly but the exception message it print in console  I do not know how to make it not printed    on console

my code

```
long time=10000;
TelnetConnection connect=new TelnetConnection();
Thread.sleep(10000); 
while(timeout > 0) {
    try {
        if(connect.connect(device)) {
            connect.disconnect();
            break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Thread.sleep(time);
        timeout-=time;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want then when the exception is thrown?

Comment: just wait  10 sec and up date time  but the exception print message  also

Comment: so where do you want the message to be printed instead?

Comment: I do not want to print the message

Comment: are you using the implementation from https://github.com/Comcast/cats/blob/master/core/cats-common/src/main/java/com/comcast/cats/telnet/TelnetConnection.java?

Comment: no but i use the same way ِapproximately

Comment: Can you share your code for TelnetConnection?

Comment: Thank you, When you asked my  for the connection code I checked it and I found the error